# Android: Sharing via Instagram : Want to avoid crop option

Tags: android, instagram

I want to skip the crop option and directly jump to share screen(Image is already square and I dont want to take user to Crop screen). Is it possible? I am using Android Intents to open Instagram.

Any help will be appreciated.